# When I try to read a matrix from a file, I get all kinds of errors, but works fine when just using data entered in

Tags: c++

When I try to read from a file using the same numbers I get errors like: the array has an unknown storage capacity.

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include <fstream> 

    using namespace std; 

    const int N = 7;
```

When I uncomment this function and try to read from a file, I get errors. This is the code that doesn't work:

```
    void readFile(int magicSquareArray[][N]);
    bool isMagicSquare(int magicSquareArray[][N]);  

    int main() 
    { 
        int magicSquareArray[][N];
```

when I change readFile(magicSquareArray[][N]); to readFile(magicSquareArray); I get the same error plus: main.cpp:19:5: error: 'readFile' was not declared in this scope

```
 readFile(magicSquareArray);
        readFile(magicSquareArray[][N]);

        if (isMagicSquare(magicSquareArray)) 
        {
            cout << "Magic Square"; 
        }
        else
            cout << "Not a magic Square"; 

        return 0; 
    }
```

Returns true if magicSquareArray[][] is magic 
square, else returns false.

```
    bool isMagicSquare(int magicSquareArray[][N]) 
    {  
        // calculate the sum of  
        // the prime diagonal 
        int sumOfDiagonal = 0; 
        int sumOfReverseDiagonal = 0; 
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
        {
            sumOfDiagonal += magicSquareArray[i][i]; 
            sumOfReverseDiagonal += magicSquareArray[i][N-  i-1];
        }

        if(sumOfDiagonal != sumOfReverseDiagonal)
           return false;

        // For sums of Rows  
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
        { 

            int calculateSumRows = 0;      
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) 
            {
                calculateSumRows += magicSquareArray[i][j]; 
            }

            // check if every row sum is 
            // equal to prime diagonal sum 
            if (calculateSumRows != sumOfDiagonal) 
                return false; 
        } 

        // For sums of Columns 
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
        { 

            int calculateSumColumns = 0;      
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) 
                calculateSumColumns += magicSquareArray[j][i]; 

            // check if every column sum is  
            // equal to prime diagonal sum 
            if (sumOfDiagonal != calculateSumColumns)  
            return false; 
        } 

        return true; 
    }
```

the file looks like this:

```
    30  39  48   1  10  19  28
    38  47   7   9  18  27  29
    46   6   8  17  26  35  37
    5   14  16  25  34  36  45
    13  15  24  33  42  44   4
    21  23  32  41  43   3  12
    22  31  40  49   2  11  20
```

this function gives me errors when I enable it:

```
    void readFile(int magicSquareArray[][N])
    {
       ifstream matrix { "360magictext.txt" };
       if (!matrix.is_open()) 
          cout << "Error! Unable to open file!";

       for (int i{}; i != N; ++i) 
       {
           for (int j{}; j != N; ++j) 
           {
               matrix >> magicSquareArray[i][j];
           }
       }
    }
```

Comment: What sort of errors do you get?

Comment: exit status 1
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:12:9: error: storage size of 'magicSquareArray' isn't known

Comment: @Newbie -- which line in your code snippets is main.cpp:12?

Comment: Oh, wait, you've posted code that **works**, and the code that's **commented out** is what doesn't work? Don't do that. Post the code that doesn't work.

Comment: `readFile(magicSquareArray[][N])` should be `readFile(magicSquareArray);`.

Comment: When I do that, I get the same error, plus an additional error:  main.cpp:19:5: error: 'readFile' was not declared in this scope
     readFile(magicSquareArray);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason you cannot use `std::vector`? This is C++ and in C++ we should be using the standard library to help us out with these kinds of things. I think your first error comes from the fact that the first `[]` in your array is empty and needs to know a number before hand. I think there might be a way around it with `size_t`if you are reading a matrix in of unknown size.

I was able to get your program to compile and run with the following changes:

```
#include <vector>

#define Matrix std::vector<std::vector<int>>

const int N = 7;
void readFile(Matrix magicSquareArray);
bool isMagicSquare(Matrix magicSquareArray);  

int main() 
{ 
  Matrix magicSquareArray(N,std::vector<int>(N));  
  readFile(magicSquareArray);
  //readFile(magicSquareArray[N][N]);

  if (isMagicSquare(magicSquareArray)) 
  {
    std::cout << "Magic Square"; 
  }
  else
    std::cout << "Not a magic Square"; 

  return 0; 
}

void readFile(Matrix magicSquareArray)
{
  std::ifstream matrix { "360magictext.txt" };
  if (!matrix.is_open()) 
    std::cout << "Error! Unable to open file!";

  for (int i = 0; i != N; ++i) 
  {
    for (int j = 0; j != N; ++j) 
    {
      matrix >> magicSquareArray[i][j];
    }
  }
}
```

What I did was `#define Matrix` by created a Matrix with a two dimensional `std::vector`'s. I then went ahead and constructed an NxN Matrix by calling `Matrix magicSquareArray(N,std::vector<int>(N));` I left the original commented out in case you still need it. However, you will still have a lot more compiler errors with your original code.

Comment: We are in a lower class and we have just got to vectors. The teacher wants us to use arrays for the matrix, but I do thank you sincerely for the help. Next project will probably involve vectors and I will look to your answer at that time.